# Trigonometric question without given diagram

Tags: trigonometry

A helicopter 750m above a point A on the ground was flying horizontally towards the east . When it was at point P , the angle of elevation from A was observed to be 60 degrees . If , after 5 seconds , the angle of elevation of the helicopter from A was observed to be 30 degrees , find the speed of the helicopter in Km/h

I drawn out the diagram below .. [image]

However , I realised that my answer is wrong after calculating . Can I get help on where did I go wrong on the diagram ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: the diagram is most likely wrong. "after 5 seconds" should be on top of P and below the jagged line.

Answer (score 1):

The "after 5 seconds" point should be **farther to the east** than point P.

At point P, the angle of elevation is $60^\circ$.  5 seconds later (that is, after the helicopter has flown **east** for 5 more seconds), the angle of elevation is $30^\circ$.  Angle of elevation **decreases** as the helicopter moves farther away from point A.  The diagram should look like this:

[image]